# calling methods from another sheet in the same book VBA

Tags: excel, vba, reference

I would like to use a function in a sheet of Excel from another module in VBA.
However I don't know why the following codes cause an error.

In sheet "proj":

```
Public Function get_value() As String
    get_value = aBox.Value 'aBox is a text box in the sheet
End Function
```

In another module:

```
Function hoge(proj As Worksheet) As String
    Dim name as string
    name = proj.get_value() 'This causes an error "method or data member not found"
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A generic Worksheet object does not have a property `get_value`, so when you declare the parameter with `proj As Worksheet`, VBA expects a generic worksheet object to work with.

Try `proj As Object`

Comment: It worked! Thank you so much. I misunderstood that once I made a function in the sheet, it can be called with a sheet name and the function name.